# Matlab integer strings decoding ... speed optimization

Tags: string, matlab, performance

I have the following problem:

I need decode integer sequences "c" to char string messages "m" by following association:

```
  numpos = 10 % ( = size(c,2)/2)
  c = [3 4 1 1 4 2 5 2 3 3,1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

Each row of "c" represents 2*numpos integers, where first numpos parameters encoded position of

```
types = {'a' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'}
```

and second numpos parameters are applied only if type contains character '@' like this:

```
  m = ' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
```

My current solution is as follows:

```
  function m = c2m(c,types)

  numpos = size(c,2)/2;

  F = cellfun(@(f) [' ' f], strrep(types,'@',':%d@'),'unif',0);
  m = arrayfun(@(f,k) sprintf(f{1},k),F(c(:,1:numpos)),c(:,numpos+(1:numpos)),'unif', 0);
  m = arrayfun(@(i) horzcat(m{i,:}), (1:numlines)', 'unif', 0)

  end
```

and the testing code is as follows:

```
  numlines = 10;
  c = repmat([3 4 1 1 4 2 5 2 3 3,1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3],numlines,1);
  types = {'a' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'};

  m = c2m(c,types);

  m =

    10×1 cell array

      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
      {' c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'}
```

The code is still too slow for me, I am looking for any speed up. In this case the most significant fraction of CPU time is spent at built-in function "sprintf".

Typical realistic sizes of problem are:

```
   numpos ~ 30 ... 60
   numlines ~ 1e4 ... 1e5
```

Any idea?

Comment: You could break your input to have more flexibility. I think of `split(types,'@')`, and separating `c` too. So that you can concatenate all the partial information in one command line.

Comment: @marsei Could you be more specific and show me your advise directly by code?

Comment: Add `@0` in `types={'a@0' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'};'` so that you can split your strings (you will remove it at the end of the process with `strrep`. Then something like `strcat(types_left, repmat(':',10,1), c(11:20), repmat('@',10,1));`. Not sure if it is faster but you can preallocate with this method.

Comment: @marsei I still do not understand what exactly you suggest me! Could you show me your idea by direct modifying of my code in this post + required modification  of input data? But, the "@" plays in my code very specific role. Not all types in general contains "@"!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 16b MATLAB shipped some new text functions that make this easy. Also in 16b MATLAB shipped the new string datatype that makes this fast.

```
 function m = c2m_new(c,types, numlines)

     types = string(types);

     num_values = size(c,2)/2;

     a = c(:,1:num_values);
     b = c(:,(num_values+1):end);

     m = types(a);
     m = insertBefore(m,"@", ":" + b);
     m = join(m,2);
 end

>> numlines = 10;
>> c = repmat([3 4 1 1 4 2 5 2 3 3,1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3],numlines,1);
>> types = {'a' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'};
>> c2m_new(c,types,numlines)

ans = 

  10×1 string array

    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
    "c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6"
```

Looking at performance:

```
>> numlines = 1E4;
>> c = repmat([3 4 1 1 4 2 5 2 3 3,1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3],numlines,1);
>> types = {'a' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'};

% My solution
>> tic; for i = 1:10; c2m_new(c,types, numlines); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.669311 seconds.

% michalkvasnicka's solution
>> tic; for i = 1:10; c2m(c,types, numlines); end; toc
Elapsed time is 23.643991 seconds.

% gnovice's solution
>> tic; for i = 1:10; c2m_gnovice(c,types, numlines); end; toc
Elapsed time is 8.960392 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to start experimenting with.

```
numpos = 10 % ( = size(c,2)/2)
c = [3 4 1 1 4 2 5 2 3 3,1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3];
types = {'a' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'}
```

Then

```
types_mod = {'a@0' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'}'; % so that each item got a @
types_mod_split = split(types_mod,'@');
m = strcat(types_mod_split(c(1:10),1), repmat({':'},10,1), num2str(c(11:20)'), repmat({'@'},10,1), types_mod_split(c(1:10),2))'
```

which gives

> m =
>     1×10 cell array
>     Columns 1 through 10
>
> {'c:1@6'} {'d:1@10'} {'a:1@0'} {'a:1@0'} {'d:2@10'} {'b:2@2'} {'e:2@11'}    {'b:3@2'} {'c:3@6'} {'c:3@6'}

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative for your `c2m` function that is 2 to 3 times faster for the typical ranges of `numpos` and `numlines` you list above:

```
function m = c2m(c, types)
  numpos = size(c, 2)/2;
  [pre, post] = strtok(types(c(:, 1:numpos)), '@');
  mid = strsplit(sprintf(' :%i', 1:max(max(c(:, numpos+1:2*numpos)))));
  mid = mid(c(:, numpos+1:2*numpos).*~cellfun(@isempty, post)+1);
  m = cellstr(char(join(strcat(pre, mid, post))));
end
```

First, the first half of `c` is split at the `'@'` using [`strtok`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html). Then a cell array `mid` is created containing the strings `{'' ':1' ':2' ... ':N'}`, where `N` is the maximum value found in the second half of `c`. This allows us to avoid costly conversion functions applied to the whole matrix (like [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), [`int2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int2str.html), etc.) by simply indexing into `mid` to get the string we want. The index is just the right half of `c` multiplied by a logical array representing whether `'@'` is present or not (gotten using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)) and incremented by 1.

Finally, the three different strings (`pre`, `mid`, and `post`) are concatenated using [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html), collected row-wise into strings using [`join`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html) (present since R2016b), then converted to a cell array of character arrays with [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) and [`char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html).

Testing it with these value:

```
numpos = 10;
numlines = 10;
c = repmat([3 4 1 1 4 2 5 2 3 3,1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3], numlines, 1);
types = {'a' 'b@2' 'c@6' 'd@10' 'e@11'};
```

We get the desired result:

```
m =

  10×1 cell array

    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
    'c:1@6 d:1@10 a a d:2@10 b:2@2 e:2@11 b:3@2 c:3@6 c:3@6'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your code is significantly slower then my code. For numlines = 1e4 is CPUmycode = 1.8sec and CPUyourcode=2.8sec.

Comment: @michalkvasnicka: I updated with a new approach. You should see significant speedup now.

Comment: How did you measure the speedup in the case of serious error on in your code?

Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in c2m
mid = mid(c(:, numpos+1:2*numpos).*double(~cellfun(@isempty, post))+1);

Comment: @michalkvasnicka: You would only get that error if you initialized `c` to an integer type. I initialized it as a double, as in your sample data.

Comment: I am afraid I have initialized c as double (as default)!!??

Comment: @michalkvasnicka: I don't know what to tell you. I ran my code exactly as above, with the data from your question, and it runs without error. Kind of a moot point though, since the answer from matlabbit seems the most efficient anyway.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was on my site... as usual :). I changed c by other functions on same matlab instance.